# Does Robot Framework support Angular2?

Tags: angular, testing, automation, robotframework

I am trying to automate an angular 2 application with the Robot Framework.

However, It does not locate any HTML attributes(id or class) within my test case.

It's throwing an error below error:

`doesn't match elements(id=accountinfo)`

Comment: I try to automate angular 2 application using robot framework. It Does't locate any key words.

It gives error like. does't match elements(id=accountinfo)

Comment: Can you please explain how you have installed the framework, how youre calling the angular elements inside the test case. Or even the test case will suffice... We need something to work with...

Comment: I add extended selenium 2 library 

we are identifying element through id, xpath,css,etc...

Value Error Element locator id=XXXXXX  xpath=//XXXXXX  did not match any elements

Comment: "doesn't match elements(id=accountinfo)" does not mean "it does not locate any keywords". If robot couldn't locate keywords you would get an entirely different error, and neither of those have anything to do with angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using Robot Framework to automate an Angular application for the last few months. Here's a few tools that'll help you.

First, Selenium2Library is actually out-dated. There is a new version, ExtendedSelenium2Library, that includes new keywords and supports Angular applications. To switch over, change all instances of the text "Selenium2Library" in your code to "ExtendedSelenium2Library". You may also need to download it separately, but it's been a while so I don't remember.

Second, you will need to learn how to read and write xpaths to at least some degree. I won't explain it completely here, but here's a tool that'll do the bulk of the grunt work for you. It won't work all the time, but it will work most of the time for an element that includes text.

```
Click Element by Text
    #   EXAMPLE USAGE
    #   Click Element by Text   "text on the element"   id="midlevellocationoftext"     button
    #   NOTE:   Does not account for extra spaces at the beginning or end, text must be exact
    #   NOTE:   Allows for injections on purpose to allow user to be more exact with their location
    [Arguments]     ${text}     ${location}=*   ${elementtype}=*
    Click Element   xpath=//*[@${location}]//${elementtype}[text()=${text}]
```

If you don't have the mid-level location of it but do have the button type, put *. That's the xpath syntax for "I don't know."

SELF-EDIT: Almost forgot, but in the HTML, ids don't use the same syntax as Robot Framework. id=someId is not necessarily equal to id="someId". Try putting quotation marks around the text of the ID.

ADDITIONAL INFO: In my more recent Angular experience, IDs and doms can both be mutable. The same locator might work on one test, but if you run a different test before it it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Robot framework will support angular2**

Yes, Its Support!

It's not working when we running a normal local server, Then I try to run the angular 2 application in `webpack-dev-server`

Then it's working fine.

add the web pack dev dependencies and run `npm install`

```html
   "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First try your xpath (or other selector) to use in developer console (e.g. Chrome dev console - hit F12 on the page and in "elements" hit CTRL+F and copy your xpath (selector) to the search line). If the element is not found here, you have wrong selector...otherwise try to use some waits in robot code (e.g. wait until element is visible)

Comment: I used x path(selectors) it does't locate,but i can locate the words.